# pronunciation of "Kunen"

Tags: set-theory, mathematicians, pronunciation

How should the last name of set theorist Ken Kunen be pronounced?  I have heard both *koo*-nen and *kyoo*-nen from other people.  Probably the best answer would be to say how he himself pronounces it, but a conditional answer (*e.g.* however the speaker says "Tuesday") might also be acceptable.

I am teaching from his book so I want to say his name correctly.

Comment: I asked Ken a couple of times, and he wouldn’t choose one; he answers to either. I generally say *kyoo*-nen, though I suspect that the original pronunciation is closer to *koo*-nen. (That was back in the 70s, so it’s conceivable that he later developed a preference.)

Comment: @Brian The first sentence sounds authoritative, so perhaps you should make it an answer.

Comment: Done! $\qquad\;$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I asked Ken a couple of times, and he wouldn’t choose one; he answers to either. I generally say *kyoo*-nen nowadays, though I suspect that the original pronunciation is closer to *koo*-nen. (That was back in the $70$s, so it’s conceivable that he later developed a preference.)